# Skip line in python

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that is laid out like this:

```
Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Num Num Num Num
Text Num Num Num Num
Text Num Num Num Num
```

My code is:

```
def readData():
    myList =[]
    myFile = open("football.txt", "r")
    for lines in myFile:
        league = lines.split()
        myList.append(league)
    return myList
```

How can I skip the first two row so I can store everything else into my list?

Comment: I would probably use `numpy.genfromtxt` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)) with `skip_header=2`

Comment: probably the shortest solution with your existing code will be `myList = myList[2:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `readlines()` for this purpose

```
myFile = open("football.txt", "r")
lines = myFile.readlines()[2:] #To skip two lines.
#rest of the code
```

You could also specify the number of lines you want to skip.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

```
def readData():
    with open("football.txt", "r") as MyFile:
        for i in range(2):
            next(myFile) # skip line
        myList = [lines.split() for lines in myFile]
    return myList
```

Comment: Another note that we also can use `f.readline()` or `f.seek()` to skip lines. Maybe clearer than `next()`...however this is also a works solution, so just a note.

Answer (score 1):

To skip lines in Python 3...

print('\n')